# Does the constructor __init__ have to be the first line of a python class (does this relate to class vs instance variables)?

Tags: python

Does `__init__()` have to be the first line of a python class or can you define variables before `__init__()` and then use `__init__()`?

If `__init__()` is not the first line of the class, are variables defined above it in the class, class variables, and variables defined below `__init__()`, instance variables?

Is `self` used to call python instance variables, but not class variables?

Comment: You might want to checkout: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes

Comment: `__init__()` does not have to be the first line or method of a class - BUT *everyone* will expect it to be the first method defined.